# Eclipse AbstractMethodError during building of JPA project

Tags: eclipse, jpa, m2eclipse, facet, jboss-tools

I have a problem with Eclipse IDE (Juno RE 2) equiped with jboss development studio. I have a few Maven projects working with JPA. In these projects, Eclipse reports an error "
This project has the JPA facet, but no JPA project could be created. See the error log for more details."

When I see the .log file in .metadata folder of the workspace, I see this exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jboss.tools.hibernate.jpt.core.internal.jpa2.HibernateJpa2_0PlatformFactory.buildJpaPlatform(Lorg/eclipse/jpt/jpa/core/JpaPlatform$Config;)Lorg/eclipse/jpt/jpa/core/JpaPlatform;
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.platform.InternalJpaPlatformConfig.buildJpaPlatform(InternalJpaPlatformConfig.java:109)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.platform.InternalJpaPlatformConfig.getJpaPlatform(InternalJpaPlatformConfig.java:102)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.platform.InternalJpaPlatformManager.getJpaPlatform(InternalJpaPlatformManager.java:288)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.getJpaPlatform(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:666)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.buildJpaProjectConfig(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:653)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.buildJpaProject(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:623)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.addJpaProject(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:604)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.buildJpaProject_(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:303)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager$BuildJpaProjectCommand.execute(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:297)
at org.eclipse.jpt.common.core.internal.utility.command.CommandJobCommandAdapter.execute(CommandJobCommandAdapter.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jpt.common.core.internal.utility.command.JobCommandJob.run(JobCommandJob.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

I really cannot find the cause of this error. Nor can I wrap my head around it. 
Any kind of explanation and or help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Alternatively, when I tell the maven to update the project, I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jpt/jpa/core/JpaFacet
at org.jboss.tools.maven.jpa.configurators.JpaProjectConfigurator.canConfigure(JpaProjectConfigurator.java:171)
at org.jboss.tools.maven.jpa.configurators.JpaProjectConfigurator.configure(JpaProjectConfigurator.java:73)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.AbstractLifecycleMapping.configure(AbstractLifecycleMapping.java:109)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:413)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:350)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:74)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem after updating my Eclipse (Kepler). I worked around that by removing the JPA Facet in the project properties. Unfortunately, this is just a temporary solution. After a "Maven" > "Update Project..." the JPA problem marker returns...

Maybe anyone comes up with a better, more permanent solution!

[image: How to remove JPA Facet from project properties]